# Как правильно задать iis rewrite rules для angularjs в подпапке?

Tags: iis, rewrite

Нужно разместить angularjs приложение в подпапке хоста. Все запросы идущие в корень сайта перенаправлять в подпапку и если нет папки или файла внутри перенаправлять на index.html игнорирую при этом путь api*.
Пример: [http://домен/(index.html)](http://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD/(index.html)) rewrite to wwwroot/(index.html). Как написать эти правила?

Comment: Хорошо, что вы нашли решение. Но в чем вопрос-то заключается?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл такое решение:

```
<rule name="Ignore api" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(api/.*)"/>
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect to wwwroot">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/{R:0}"/>
</rule>
<rule name="Short URLs" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/" />
</rule>
```

Но с таким решением есть одна проблема, если в пути есть название существующей папки в "wwwroot/..." но без слеша в конце то путь переписывается как "wwwroot/название папки/" и соответственно не находится.